# Unification of expanded terms, double negation

Tags: prolog, unification

I need to introduce a predicate that will let me negate atoms. So far I have `neg(Premise) :- \+ Premise.`, which gives me following results:

```
?- assert(a).
true.

?- a.
true.

?- neg(a).
false.

?- neg(neg(a)).
true.
```

That makes sense and all is dandy, *until* I tried unification. For instance

`[a,_] = [a,123].` returns `true.`

while

`[a,_] = [neg(neg(a)),123].` returns `false.`.

How can I solve this so that the `neg(neg(X))` part is being evaluated or otherwise unified with `X` (since they both are logically equivalent)? So basically, I need `X=neg(a), a=neg(X).` to succeed.

**Edit** I found an explanation as to *why* `not(not(<expression>))` is not equivalent to `<expression>` in prolog. Since `<expression>` succeeds, `not(<expression>)` fails. When a goal fails the variables it instantiated get uninstantiated. ([source](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~ajuma/326f08/20Prolog5.pdf), slide 14).

I'm still not sure how to get around this though.

Comment: Prolog isn't executing a predicate like a function and returning a result. It instantiates uninstantiated variables where possible and checks for truth value. So `neg(neg(a))` isn't doing what you might think. It's instantiating `Premise` with `neg(a)` and then evaluating `\+ neg(a).` ultimately determining the truth value of `neg` with `neg(a)` given as a term. Your array example attempts to unify `a` with `neg(neg(a))` and fails because they are both fully instantiated terms that don't match. You'll need to be more clear on what you're trying to do in order to 'get around it'.

Comment: @mbratch I see. Basically what I want is: if `l(a).` holds, then `l(neg(neg(a)).` should succeed too. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. You want a predicate that says, `l(neg(neg(X))) :- l(X).`

Comment: @mbratch and if I want that to hold for all predicates? Copy & paste and substitute `l` for each predicate seems like not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Indeed, if you are looking for a general solution, that wouldn't be efficient. I'm a little curious as to what's driving the scenario to be so prevalent. Some refactoring may be necessary.

Comment: @mbratch Basically I need `a` to match `neg(X)` where `X` gets instantiated to `neg(a)`. If you are curious as to the context I can send you the code on chat, if you'd like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40589/discussion-between-mbratch-and-0sh)

Answer (score 1):

Reification of truth value will work on your simple case:

```
4 ?- [user].
|: reify(P, V) :- call(P) -> V = 1 ; V = 0.
% user://1 compiled 0.03 sec, 2 clauses
true.

5 ?- reify(true, V), reify(\+ \+ true, U), V = U.
V = U, U = 1.
```

using your symbols:

```
6 ?- [user].
|: a.
|: neg(P) :- \+ P.
% user://2 compiled 0.02 sec, 3 clauses
true.

7 ?- reify(a, V), reify(neg(neg(a)), U), V = U.
V = U, U = 1.
```

not sure how well this will merge with your code.